# Where is conf/elasticsearch.yml file in Elassandra Docker image?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, cassandra, elassandra

I am trying to using elassandra (which is elasticsearch + cassandra) in Docker image, so I am beginner with it. In such case, my question can be beginner level, sorry for that :)

I have started that docker image and I'm able to inserting data and searching it but I don't know how to create a new cluster. According to this documentation I need to find elasticsearch.yml file in my image but I couldn't find it via docker cli terminal: https://elassandra.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html

So far I tried to use "find . elasticsearch.yml" command but there is no file like that in entire directories of image.

[image]

Thanks for your attention. Have a nice day!

Comment: Hmm.  I'm not sure where it is in the image, but I think it ends up in `/etc/cassandra/`.  Not sure if that helps you or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like Aaron is correct. According to the code, it is injected into the same location as `cassandra.yaml` which is `/etc/cassandra`.

Source: [`docker-entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/strapdata/docker-elassandra/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh#L38-L40)

```
# usage:
#   config_injection CASSANDRA $CASSANDRA_CONFIG/cassandra.yaml
#   config_injection ELASTICSEARCH $CASSANDRA_CONFIG/elasticsearch.yml
```

Source: [`Dockerfile`](https://github.com/strapdata/docker-elassandra/blob/master/Dockerfile#L166)

```
ENV CASSANDRA_CONFIG /etc/cassandra
```

Answer (score 2):

Converting my comment to an answer...

I'm not sure where it is in the image.  But I remember reading that it ends up in `/etc/cassandra/`, same place as the `cassandra.yaml`.

Thanks to Erick for the validation!